# numerical keypad not working on laptop

Tags: keyboard, opensuse, hardware

I just installed open SUSE tumbleweed in this [hp 15-bs0xx](http://www8.hp.com/cl/es/products/laptops/product-detail.html?oid=16748292#!tab=specs), but the numerical keypad is not working as numerical, instead it moves the mouse cursor.

I have tested this in mate and xfce environments.
At the same time the Fn keys (Fn+any F key) did not work too.

Comment: Have you tried turning Mouse Keys off?

Comment: Yes.  But it didn’t fix it.

Comment: You should test this in a kernel virtual terminal, too, outwith X11's input handling, and add what you find to the question with [edit].  This will either suggest or eliminate potential answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure mouse keys isn't affecting your keyboard, the hacky way you could try is to manually set each key.

- run `xev` to find the keycode for a key.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> this keycode in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` to find corresponding key symbol (might be more than one, look for `KP_4` for key 4, etc...).
- add `key <KEYSYM> { [ NUMBER ] };` to  the `xkb_symbols` section of your keyboard layout file (eg. `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` for default US layout).
- repeat for each keypad key and reboot to apply changes.

Note: You might want to try mapping a key with `xmodmap -e 'keycode KEYCODE = NUMBER'` way first to see if it actually *works* before trying the steps above to make changes permanent.

Answer (score 1):

OK, there seems to be related to bios conflicts or a bad ACPI implementation.
There is an option in the bios that says "Action Keys" , this enable the Fn+Fx combinations or simply the Fx key.

I set the option to disabled, and that worked out.

The answer by jack11111 is a smart one, but I didn’t try out.